# Laravel - whereHas and whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to get the posts where the post has tag1 AND tag2 (or more)

I've tried this:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function(Builder $query) {
    foreach (request('tags') as $tag) { // request('tags') = integer array
        $query->where('id', $tag);
    }
})->get();
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to get post where has tag1 **AND** tag2 you can do with below code

```
$posts = Post::query();
foreach (request('tags') as $tag) { // request('tags') = integer array
    $posts = $posts->whereHas('tags', function(Builder $query) use ($tag) {
        $query->where('id', $tag);
    });
}
$posts = $posts->get();
```

But if you meant want to get posts where has tag1 **OR** tag2.

You can use `whereIn` method:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function(Builder $query) {
    $query->whereIn('id', request('tags'));
})->get();
```

or alternative use `orWhere`

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function(Builder $query) {
    foreach (request('tags') as $tag) { // request('tags') = integer array
        $query->orWhere('id', $tag);
    }
})->get();
```

Comment: Hi, I need the AND, I already did the OR exactly as your example. 
I'm gonna check my query with debugbar to figure out why is not working then.

Comment: @Giovani Sorry, I missunderstood with your intent. I updated my answer